# returning an array value inside a function in php

Tags: php

i want a function to echo values defined in arrays, the same array defined inside arguments of the same functon, like this:

```
function something($somena = "rahul", $somepla = "delhi", $color = "red"){
    $somena = array("amit", "rohit", "girish");
    $somepla = array("bombay", "cochin", "agra");
    $color = array("magenta", "mauve", "green");
    return "my name is  $somena[2], my place of birth is $somepla[1] and my color is $color[2]";

    }
    echo "<br/>",something();
    echo "<br/>",something($somena[0]);
```

Here,the first echo is outputted fine, but i have problem in the second echo, because it is not able to recognize $somena[0]). pls explain why it is happening and what is the workaround. you can see what i am after: i want to just keep on echoing the function with specific calls to the array. so it can go like:

```
echo "<br/>",something($somepla[1], $color[2]);
```

and so on.

Comment: I think you need to do some research on scope.

Comment: Your problem is *solvable* probably, but I deleted my answer because the intend of the function is more than unclear, you are trying something weird there. "*Given a name, overwrite it with an array*" Doesn't make sense to pass names when you overwrite it anyway.

Comment: define $somena array first.

Answer (score 0):

one thing i noticed you are passing $somena[0] to function something. But this array is not defined it's defined in the function scope.

So remove this one first or define array out of the function.
I tested both echo statements working fine and giving same output.

Comment: thats what the problem is: both statements giving same output. anyways, i tried your idea of defining array outside of function, but no effect

Comment: then i think you didn't change the variable in return statement. m i right ?

Answer (score 0):

```
function something($array){
    $somena = array("amit", "rohit", "girish");
    $somepla = array("bombay", "cochin", "agra");
    $color = array("magenta", "mauve", "green");
    return ('my name is ' . $somena[$array[0]] . ', my place of birth is ' . 
$somepla[$array[1]] . ' and my color is ' . $color[$array[2]]);
    }   

    $data = array(0,1,2);
    echo "<br/>",something();
    echo "<br/>",something($data);
```

Output:
my name is , my place of birth is and my color is
my name is amit, my place of birth is cochin and my color is green

```
    function something($name,$place,$color){
        $names = array('unknown','amit', 'rohit', 'girish');
        $places = array('unknown','bombay', 'cochin', 'agra');
        $colors = array('unknown','magenta', 'mauve', 'green');
        settype($name,'int');  //   if variable not passed, it will be set to zero (unknown)
        settype($place,'int'); //    or if passed as a string will and  
        settype($color,'int'); //     be set to correct type for array
        return ("my name is $names[$name], my place of birth is $places[$place], and my color is $colors[$color]");
        }

        $n = 1;
        $p = 2;
        $c = 3;
echo "<br/>",something($name,$place,$color);
echo "<br/>",something($n,$p,$c);
```

Output:
my name is unknown, my place of birth is unknown, and my color is unknown
my name is amit, my place of birth is cochin, and my color is green

Answer (score 0):

This is could be useful (link here - http://viper-7.com/QTx8mq):

```
<?php

  // $add - if need to add new values to array
  function something($somena_ID = 2, $somepla_ID = 1, $color_ID = 2,$add=0){

    //Arrays:
    $somena  = array("amit",    "rohit",  "girish");
    $somepla = array("bombay",  "cochin", "agra"  );
    $color   = array("magenta", "mauve",  "green" );

    //Overwrites:
    if (!is_int($somena_ID)){  $somena_ID  = (array_push ($somena,  $somena_ID)  - 1);  $somena_  = 1;}else{$somena_  = 0;}
    if (!is_int($somepla_ID)){ $somepla_ID = (array_push ($somepla, $somepla_ID) - 1);  $somepla_ = 1;}else{$somepla_ = 0;}
    if (!is_int($color_ID)){   $color_ID   = (array_push ($color,   $color_ID)   - 1);  $color_   = 1;}else{$color_   = 0;}

    //return
    if ($add){
      return "my name is $somena[$somena_ID], my place of birth is $somepla[$somepla_ID] and my color is $color[$color_ID]";
    }else{
      return "my name is ".          ($somena_  ?array_pop($somena) : $somena[$somena_ID]) .", 
              my place of birth is ".($somepla_ ?array_pop($somepla):$somepla[$somepla_ID])." 
              and my color is ".     ($color_   ?array_pop($color)  :  $color[$color_ID])  ."";
    }
  }

echo "<br/>",something();
echo "<br/>",something(0);
echo "<br/>",something(0, "delhi", "red"); // return values and not changed arrays
echo "<br/>",something(0, "delhi", 2); // return values and not changed arrays
echo "<br/>",something("rahul", "delhi", "red",0); // return values and not changed arrays
echo "<br/>",something("rahul", "delhi", "red",1); // return values and add values to arrays

?>
```

Output:

```
my name is girish, my place of birth is cochin and my color is green
my name is amit, my place of birth is cochin and my color is green
my name is amit, my place of birth is delhi and my color is red
my name is amit, my place of birth is delhi and my color is green
my name is rahul, my place of birth is delhi and my color is red
my name is rahul, my place of birth is delhi and my color is red
```